# How to different Widget depending on paramater Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show different Icon depending on my paramater, I manage to show it using If statement but I have to back my screen first and reload it again, I tried to use setState but I got some error

> error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used. (use_of_void_result at [tiket_kerja] lib\screens\main_pages\main_detail_ticket_page.dart:2915)

How can I fix this ?

Here's the code:

```
Column[
TextButton();
setState(() {
 if (progress ==0) 
  if (fileExistList[index] ==true)
      Icon(Icons.done);
  else
      Icon(Icons.close);
  else
      Text('$progress');
})
]
```

Comment: you have two else statement.

Answer (score 0):

create a function and call it with value you want

```
int progress = 0;
bool fileExist = true;
Widget getIcon(int progress, bool fileExist) {

 if (progress == 0) 
  if (fileExist)
      return Icon(Icons.done);
  else
      return Icon(Icons.close);
  else
      return Text('$progress');
}

Column(
    childreen: [
             TextButton(),
             getIcon(progress, fileExist),
            ]
)
```

now when ever you want to change the icon just call

```
setState(() {
 //change value of the paramaters
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show two icons, create a relatable Boolean variable and set it to false initially, here, `_fileExists = false` initially.

Overtime you could change the value to true using `setState()` so that flutter knows that something has changed and it needs to rebuild the widget.

To show icons depending on the value of `_fileExists`, you can use ternary operation. It's generally you pass a true or false statement followed by question mark (?) and output in each case.

Here this could be used as `_fileExists(as it only returns true or false) ? Icon(Icons.done) : Icon(Icons.close)`

Here, `Icon(Icons.done)` is returned only if `_fileExists` is true, else returns `Icon(Icons.close)`

Ternary operators is in the form of

```
`condition ? return_this_if_true : return_this_if_false`
```

Comment: Learn more about ternary operators in flutter here: https://youtu.be/NDulhXVcLuI

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```html
Column(childreen: [
    TextButton(),
    (progress == 0 && fileExistList[index] == true)
        ? Icon(Icons.done)
        : (progress == 0 && fileExistList[index] == false)
            ? Icon(Icons.close)
            : Text('$progress'),
  ]);
```